Merging dataframes in a specific with Scala Spark
Let's say I have the following 2 dataframes in Scala Spark:
Dataframe holding all processed records:



ID
Name
Color
ProcessingTimestamp
AnotherTimestamp




1
Bob
blue
171057948
171057948


2
Alice
orange
1711057948
1711057948


1
Bob
pink
172057948
172057741



Dataframe containing updates:



ID
Name
Color
ProcessingTimestamp
AnotherTimestamp




1
Bob
pink
172058000
172058000


2
Alice
blue
172058000
172058000


3
Stacy
red
172058000
172058000



After merging the updates into the main dataframe, I would like the main dataframe to look like this:



ID
Name
Color
ProcessingTimestamp
AnotherTimestamp




1
Bob
blue
171057948
171057948


2
Alice
orange
1711057948
1711057948


1
Bob
pink
172058000
172058000


2
Alice
blue
172058000
172058000


3
Stacy
red
172058000
172058000



Meaning the algo in words is:

If a row from the update dataframe already exists in the main data frame, where the columns values are identical except the timestamp columns, then instead of adding a new row to main dataframe, just update the timestamp values in the existing matching row.
If a row with the same ID exists, but some properties (Name and Color in this example) are updated, insert a completely new row with the same ID and the timestamps from the update dataframe
If ID doesnt exist in main dataframe, just insert it as is (so same as the 2nd case)

I am new to scala and spark, how could I achieve this functionality? Ideally the function signature would look somewhat like this:
import org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame

def mergeDataFrames(mainDF: DataFrame, updateDF: DataFrame, mergeColumns: Seq[String], updateColumns: Seq[String]): DataFrame = {
//mergeColumns: ID, Name, Color
//updateColumns: ProcessingTimestamp, AnotherTimestamp
}

Thank you for the help.

How would you do this in SQL or Python ? :)

There are at least three ways:
Group by all Keys
If ID, Name and Color are the only logic you really need:
import sparkSession.implicits._
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions.{collect_list, struct}
val original = Seq(
  (1,   "Bob",  "blue", 171057948,  171057948),
  (2,   "Alice",    "orange",   1711057948, 1711057948),
  (1,   "Bob", "pink",  172057948,172057741),
).toDF("ID","Name","Color","ProcessingTimestamp","AnotherTimestamp").selectExpr("*","'o' source")

val updated = Seq(
  (1,   "Bob",  "pink", 172058000,  172058000),
  (2,   "Alice",    "blue", 172058000,  172058000),
  (3,   "Stacy", "red", 172058000,172058000),
).toDF("ID","Name","Color","ProcessingTimestamp","AnotherTimestamp").selectExpr("*","'u' source")

val grouped = original.union(updated).groupBy("ID","Name","Color").agg(collect_list(struct("ProcessingTimestamp","AnotherTimestamp", "source")).as("grouped"))
val filtered = grouped.selectExpr("ID","Name","Color", "element_at(if(array_size(grouped) = 1, grouped, filter(grouped, x -> x.source = 'u')),1) structy").
  selectExpr("*","structy.*").drop("structy", "source")
filtered.show

i.e. after unioning group by your key fields and collect your fact fields, where the is a single row in the grouped data it's got no update, where it's more than one take the update (if there are more than one update you could use an aggregate like below with extra logic).
Logic is exactly as described by OP
Full join and some field based select based on the update source being there or not:
// full join then filter
val updatedNewNames = updated.selectExpr("ID","Name","Color","ProcessingTimestamp as UProcessingTimestamp","AnotherTimestamp as UAnotherTimestamp", "source")
val joinedAndFiltered =
  original.drop("source").join(updatedNewNames, Seq("ID", "Name", "Color"), "full").
    selectExpr("ID", "Name", "Color", "if(source is null, ProcessingTimestamp, UProcessingTimestamp) ProcessingTimestamp",
      "if(source is null, AnotherTimestamp, UAnotherTimestamp) AnotherTimestamp")
joinedAndFiltered.show

I really need more complicated logic
If your really want to go hard or have more exacting logic, you can union, collect_list and sprinkle in "some" transforms.
val groupedForMap = original.union(updated).groupBy("ID").agg(collect_list(struct("Name","Color","ProcessingTimestamp","AnotherTimestamp", "source")).as("grouped"))

val mapped =
  groupedForMap.selectExpr("id",
  """map_filter(
   aggregate(grouped, map(named_struct('Name','','Color',''),named_struct('ProcessingTimestamp',0,'AnotherTimestamp',0, 'source', '-')),
  (acc, x) ->
    if(acc[struct(x.Name, x.Color)] is null,
      -- we can just add to it with this awesome syntax
      map_concat(acc, map(struct(x.Name, x.Color), struct(x.ProcessingTimestamp, x.AnotherTimestamp, x.source))),
      if(acc[struct(x.Name, x.Color)].source = 'o' and x.source = 'u',
        -- we need to replace with this even more convoluted syntax
        map_concat( map_filter(acc, (k,v) -> k != struct(x.Name, x.Color)), map(struct(x.Name, x.Color), struct(x.ProcessingTimestamp, x.AnotherTimestamp, x.source))),
        acc
      )
      )),
      -- get rid of the starter
      (k, v) -> k != named_struct('Name','','Color','')
       ) mapped
      """)

val expanded = mapped.selectExpr("id","explode(mapped)").selectExpr("id","key.*","value.*")
expanded.show

all yields (source on the hard mode example):
+---+-----+------+-------------------+----------------+------+
| id| Name| Color|ProcessingTimestamp|AnotherTimestamp|source|
+---+-----+------+-------------------+----------------+------+
|  1|  Bob|  blue|          171057948|       171057948|     o|
|  1|  Bob|  pink|          172058000|       172058000|     u|
|  2|Alice|orange|         1711057948|      1711057948|     o|
|  2|Alice|  blue|          172058000|       172058000|     u|
|  3|Stacy|   red|          172058000|       172058000|     u|
+---+-----+------+-------------------+----------------+------+

the extra "source" field is needed to tell new from old.
